# Extending BIRT using Programming by Example concept

Tags: eclipse-rcp, birt, autofill

Can the following be achieved using eclipse BIRT ?                                                                                                     Consider a dataset with some 1000 records .Get 20 records after randomizing them.
The user selects few rows and columns(say checkboxes are provided for selection) of his interest among the 20.
Based on his selection can "SELECT" queries be predicted.
Basically, can "PROGRAMMING BY EXAMPLE" concept be used to suggest query in a brute-force manner.

Employee table
id first_name last_name  email  gender  mobile  salary

Answer (score 0):

No, this feature is not supported by BIRT.

Answer (score 0):

Since BIRT can be called launched with APIs and URLs, the functionality you describe above can easily be accomplished on a JSP page (or RCP screen if thats what you are doing) and then the query can be passed into a BIRT rptdesign.  With a little bit of report scripting, a table and columns can be added.  There are lots of examples floating around of dynamically adding tables and columns with BIRT scripting.

Comment: Virgil, could you mention few examples. Thanks

Comment: Lots of examples? I know of exactly one example - and it was incomplete, because the information about the columns had to be given from outside - the report itself is not able to do so (and I failed when I tried that as well). Apart from that, it *is* possible to do this; however doing this inJavaScript is a lot of trial and error... Better do this in Java. Anyway, it takes a an experienced BIRT developer...